# Merging row cells in Vaadin Grid using jQuery

Tags: jquery, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I would like to merge certain cells into a vaadin grid that has the same value. Is there a vaadin-way to do this?
[grid with duplicate cell value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4syI.png)

[grid after cell merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BpPw.png)

So far I have achieved the desired result only using jQuery but outside vaadin environment. If there is no vaadin-way to merge the cells, is there a way to integrate jQuery script into vaadin and perform the merge?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no official way to merge cells in the Vaadin Grid.

Like you’ve done with jQuery, it may be possible to hack the internals with JavaScript. But that will likely break in one way or multiple ways. For example, if you have a lot of data rows/items, the merged cell will be reused for other rows/items when you scroll the grid (a.k.a. virtualized scrolling). Some of your data will not be visible because of that, and you will probably get a JS error as well, as the grid can't find a cell element that it expects to find (the one you merged and therefore removed).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and answer. By the way, are we going to have this feature (cell merge) officially in Vaadin grid anytime soon?

Comment: If you plan to use Grid more as a layout, you could try some of the add-ons, like https://vaadin.com/directory/component/html-table

Comment: @TatuLund Unfortunately, the grid we are using is dynamic and we are also trying to avoid any plugins/add-ons.

I was able to merge the Vaadin Grid cells easily with the help of css in components/vaadin-grid.css. However, I want to do it programatically using Javascript/jQuery. 

In order to run any js or jQuery script, which ts file should be used? In other words, where can I place the script in Vaadin directory?

Thanks!

Comment: I have this script in place which I have embeded inside index.html. 

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#vaadin-grid").each(function() {
      console.log("this is my log");

      $(this).find("td:first").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == $(this).closest("tr").prev().find("td:first").text();
      }).addClass("duplicate");
    });
  });
</script>

However, I am not able to find the locator #vaadin-grid. Hence, my console.log function is not executed.

Comment: jQuery does not work with web components, which have their internals in Shadow DOM. Vaadin's component implementations are such. So jQuery is pretty much useless for this.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I would assume you can use jQuery to access elements in a shadow root as well. Something like `$($('vaadin-grid').shadowRoot)`